# Apache 2.4 reachable but refusing the connection

Tags: apache-http-server, connection, telnet

Not a duplicate, please be patient while trying to flag as duplicate. Thanks.

**Environment:**

- Mac OS X EL Capitan 64 bit
- Apache 2.4.25 (Unix)

**ping**

```
ping 127.0.0.1
```

returns:

> 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.081 ms
> 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.111 ms
> ...

**telnet:**

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 80
```

returns:

> Trying 127.0.0.1...
> telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

**scutil:**

```
scutil -r localhost
```

returns:

> Reachable

**configtest:**

```
apachectl configtest
```

returns:

> Syntax OK

**$PATH**

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Several `apachectl restart`s & Complete system restarts with no success!
What is the problem with my Apache installation?

## Update 1

**curl**

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1
```

returns:

> Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1/
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
> connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
> Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
> Closing connection 0
> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused

## Update 2

**lsof**

```
lsof -i:80
```

returns:

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google    349 peyman  126u  IPv4 0x23528848eb5fe4db      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.102:49238->ec2-54-197-238-119.compute-1.amazonaws.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    349 peyman  147u  IPv4 0x23528848ec35769b      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.102:49286->151.101.193.69:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    349 peyman  164u  IPv4 0x23528848ebfa413b      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.102:49290->ec2-23-23-98-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    349 peyman  170u  IPv4 0x23528848ebfa031b      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.102:49242->pixel.quantserve.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    349 peyman  188u  IPv4 0x23528848ec330dbb      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.102:49248->151.101.65.69:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    349 peyman  189u  IPv4 0x23528848ebe7185b      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.102:49308->ec2-23-21-110-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    349 peyman  208u  IPv4 0x23528848ec35885b      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.102:49272->a72-247-178-186.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: What do you get with `curl -v http://127.0.0.1/` and what is in the error logs?

Comment: Please check **Update 1**

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any evidence in what you've posted of Apache even listening on port 80; I only see outbound connectivity to port 80 on other systems. The `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` command doesn't show Apache is reachable; you would see the same results if you used port 81, 85, 800, etc. Issue the command `netstat -a | grep http | grep LISTEN` ; you should see a line with "*.http" and "LISTEN" at the end of the line, if Apache is actually listening for connections on port 80. E.g., see [Running an Apache web server under OS X El Capitan](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/apache/).

If you don't see a line of output indicating it is listening on port 80, but are merely returned to the Bash shell prompt, then issue the command `sudo apachectl start` then issue the netstat command again. If you now see that a process is listening on port 80, you can then try your telnet command again. If Apache is responding on port 80, you should then see `Escape character is '^]'.` At that point you can issue the command `HEAD / HTTP/1.0` and then hit enter a couple of times. You should see Apache respond with output similar to the following output:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
HEAD / HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 11 Mar 2017 01:44:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) PHP/5.5.38
Last-Modified: Fri, 03 Feb 2017 21:44:57 GMT
ETag: "a8-547a7315f6840"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 168
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Thanks but I ended up with whole system setup from the beginning, as That was really annoying